# Ui.Bootstrap Typeahead not working with Async call

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sails.js, angular-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using ui.bootstrap typeahead with an async call. However the resulting data does not seem to be finding it ways back to the typeahead directive and subsequently no dropdown appears with data.

The html is

```
<input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Search Profile" typeahead="username.username for username in getSearch($viewValue)" typeahead-wait-ms="400" class="form-control">
```

And the JS function is here

```
$scope.getSearch = function (val) {

    return $sails.get("/search/" + val).success(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response.map(function (item) {
            console.log(item.username);
            return item.username;
        });

    }).error(function (response) {
        console.log('The sails profile search has failed');
    });

}
```

The response JSON object is

```
Object
@type: "d"
id: "#17:3"
username: "Burt"
__proto__: Object
```

I am using angular-sails on the client to query the backend. I have tested the code with the sample given on the ui.bootstrap documentation and everything works ok.

The $sails.get also works as the console.log(item.username) prints out the values.

I have a feeling its got to do with the promise in the getSearch function.

Any ideas why the dropdown is not appearing?

Answer (score 0):

I updated the sails from 10.5 to 11. Subsequently the client SDK changed (Sails.io) and the angular libraries I was using Angular-Sails also needed to be updated.

The promise functions changed and i needed to update it. Changing the promise function to the one below fixed the problem. Now the typeahead function gets a response and the dropdown appears.

```
    return $sails.get("/search/" + val)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            return response.data.map(function (item) {
                return item.username;
            });
        }, function (response) {
            alert('Houston, we got a problem!');
        });
```

Comment: In my case, the promise function is working but the the return data somehow not coming to the dropdown. But I checked with static data, it's working fine.